# Extract full HTML of a website by using pyppeteer in python

Tags: python, pyppeteer

I'm using the below code to extract full HTML:
`cont = await page1.content()`
The website I intend to extract from is:
https://www.mohmal.com/en

which is a website to make temporary email accounts. The exact thing I want to do is reading the content of received emails, but by using the above code, I could not extract inner frame HTML where received emails contents placed within it. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using urllib?
You can use the `urllib` module to read html websites.

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
f = urlopen("https://www.google.com")
print(f.read())
f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's a project that uses pyppeteer library to run the browser and performs some functions on some websites including the mentioned website. In this case, the program opens the above website, creates an email, and refreshes the website for incoming emails. Therefore I have no fixed URL to put into the library you have suggested.